# Android: No logs while logging via slf4j-android

Tags: android, logging, slf4j

I use library which uses sfl4j-api for logging in android application. So I use slf4j-android to get logs, but I only got following messages:

```
I/AndroidLoggerFactory(  267): Logger name 'org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'o*.a*.m*.u*.NamePreser*' instead.
```

And no more logs from that library, but I see in code there are plenty of them. 
I tried to change the level of logging for tags in emulator by:

```
emulator -avd default -debug '*'
```

or by

```
emulator -avd default -verbose
```

and nothing changed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer at last.
`LOG.isDebugEnabled()` always returns false even if `LOG.debug(msg)` has printed message in ddms. I have just got rid of `LOG.isDebugEnabled()`.

Comment: You should never use `isDebugEnabled` when using slf4j. [This post](http://blog.mediasoft.be/dont-clutter-your-code-with-isdebugenabled/) explains why.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried [original slf4j.org-android](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) but unfortunately this jar was not able to get debug/verbose messages to be logged as explained by @kogut-s answer.

currently i link against the alternative [lp0-slf4j-android](https://github.com/lp0/slf4j-android) implementation that uses a properties-file with the logging settings where i can also get debug/verbose messages if enabled.